# Oracle Compare 2 equijoined tables

Tags: oracle, cursor

The concept is that i am trying to compare 2 equijoined tables to see if the whether the other query has the same values or if they exist in the other query.
The way i join the tables is:
 "select a.sth, a.sth2, a.st3, b.value for table1 a, table2 b where a.key = b.valkey"
This will result in displaying the values columns of table1 and next the column value2 from table2 where their key is the same.
Now i have another 2 tables which contain similar data and i want to check if the results of my query exists in the query i will build for the other tables like:
"select a.sth, a.sth2, a.st3, b.value for table3 a, table4 b where a.key = b.valkey"

The only way i thought of doing this was with nested implicit cursors. Like for example:

```
BEGIN
     FOR item IN (select a.sth, a.sth2, a.st3, b.value for table1 a, table2 b where a.key = b.valkey)
     LOOP
Begin
FOR item2 IN (select a.sth, a.sth2, a.st3, b.value for table3 a, table4 b where a.key = b.valkey)
  LOOP
    Begin
if (item1.sth = item2.sth) and (item1.sth2 = item2.sth2) and (item1.sth3 = item2.sth3) and (item1.value = item2.value) Then
dbms_output.put_line("Found and value is the same");
Elsif (item1.sth = item2.sth) and (item1.sth2 = item2.sth2) and (item1.sth3 = item2.sth3) and Not (item1.value = item2.value) Then 
dbms_output.put_line("Found but value is different");
Exception When no_data_found then
dbms_output.put_line("item1 was not found in table3");
End;
  END LOOP;
End;
 END LOOP;
 END;
```

The above is just pseudo code of what i thought to do. Can i do something like this or is there an alternative that has better performance which i can use? I am looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need cursors for this.  In general, set-based code is going to work better.  The query would look something like this:

```
select coalesce(a.key, b.valkey) as thekey,
       a.sth, a.sth2, a.st3, b.value
       (case when a.key is null then 'Not found in a'
             when b.key is null then 'Not found in b'
             when (a.sth = b.sth) and (a.sth2 = b.sth2) and (a.sth3 = b.sth3) and
                  (a.value = b.value)
             then 'Found and same'
             when (a.sth = b.sth) and (a.sth2 = b.sth2) and (a.sth3 = b.sth3) and
                  (a.value <> b.value)
             then 'Found and different'
             else 'Other!!!'
        end)
from table1 a full outer join
     table2 b 
     on a.key = b.valkey
```

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't understand exactly how this can help me.. The concept is that i have 2 tables on one hand that are joined based on a value.

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgiou . . . This query does pretty much what the PL/SQL code does, except it uses SQL instead of a cursor.  That should make it run faster.

Comment: So this is going to check if the values of the combination of the first 2 tables (1,2) exist in the other 2 tables (3,4) and if they have the same values? I was trying to read through the documentation but i got confused how this thing happens